# URL rewrite for users and admin directory

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My web root looks like this

- /www

  - /admin

    - index.php
  - index.php
  - .htaccess

The thing I want to do:

1. All URLs of type /anything-here should go to index.php
2. All URLs of type /admin/anything-here should go to admin/index.php
3. User authentication when entering admin section

For now this is what I have in my .htacces

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# For users
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/.*
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the BasicHTTPAuthentication section as you can find it on multiples sites in your admin .htaccess

You can use ,

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ /admin/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

The .htaccess basic auth will take care of the authentication in the subdir.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the prefix `admin/` optional:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(admin/)?.* $1index.php
```